# Shell command to copy file from one server to remote server with different user

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I have a server serverA and a user on it with "`akotha`", and there is another user "`mqm`". I can switch to "`mqm`" by typing `sudo su - mqm`, but I don't know the password of the `mqm` user. All I want is to copy a file from my localserver to serverA and place it in a folder which only `mqm` has write access to.

Can you please let me know the command to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: That kinda goes against the whole idea of security.  If only mqm has write access to a folder, then only mqm can put stuff there.  If you don't have the password for mqm, you're not allowed to do that.  Suppose akotha and mqm were co-workers and akotha wanted mqm's job -- if akotha put evidence of embezzlement or other crime in a folder that only mqm is allowed to write to, it would sure look like mqm was guilty, thus getting him fired and letting akotha take his job.  So, no, if only mqm is allowed to write to a folder, than only mqm can write to that folder.  You'll have to find another way.

Comment: There's a moderate chance that the `mqm` user (message queue manager?) is a shared administrative account that runs an application.  Under such circumstances, it isn't so unreasonable to use `sudo`, though any shared user ID is a risk.  The `su` manual page tells you how to run commands (other than a login shell) as the nominated user.  Go, read!

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH and secure copy command:

```
$ scp path/to/local/file mqm@ip_address_of_server_A:~/directory
```

but if you haven't the password of 'mqm' you can send it to user 'akotha' and then change file permissions

Comment: The folder doesn't have permissions for akotha user to place files.
only mqm user can place the files. i found the below command is useful but not sure this is a correct one 



TEXT=`cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` ssh user@host -t sudo "bash -c \"echo '$TEXT' > foo.pub\""

Comment: Yes, using ssh-keys is the solution: append your id_dsa.pub (or id_rsa.pub) to file `~mqm/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Check the permissions/access rights: for directory `~mqm/ssh` it's owner=mqm, rigths=0700; for files in ~/mqm/.ssh: owner=mqm, rights=0600

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that would work to fulfill the requirement.